# Power Bi Kpi Matrix Chart

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I built a report in power bi with **Power Kpi matrix custom chart** below attached image is my expectation as per Microsoft Documentation [here](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104381299).

[image]

Everything is working fine but in **Kpi status icon** (triangle,circle,diamond) fields are not appearing .

[image]

Anyone please help find what's getting wrong.

Comment: something wrong with microsoft implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a column with a KPI "flag" value that you can then assign the "flag" value in the format section under KPI indicator. IE, IF (achieved value is < Milestone, 1, If (achieved value < Milestone, -1, 0))